# R evalute formulas in a list of formulas

Tags: r, eval

I have a list of formulas like this:

```
ATi<-list(quote(-(1/(C1 * Rf) + (1/(C1 * Rc) + (1/(C1 * Rint) + 1/(C1 * Rei))))),

      quote(1/(C1 * Rei)), 0, quote(1/(C1 * Rint)), quote(1/(C1 * Rf)),
      quote(1/(C1 * Rc)), 0, 0)

List of 8
$ : language -(1/(C1 * Rf) + (1/(C1 * Rc) + (1/(C1 * Rint) + 1/(C1 * Rei))))
$ : language 1/(C1 * Rei)
$ : num 0
$ : language 1/(C1 * Rint)
$ : language 1/(C1 * Rf)
$ : language 1/(C1 * Rc)
$ : num 0
$ : num 0
```

I want to evaluate each formula after insert the value of each parameter that I have in other list. As output I want a list of result.
I try different approach but I did found the solution. I Have several of that and I'd like smart solution to automize this process.

First I insert the value of the parameters. ATi is my list name and value is the list where the value and the name of parameters are stored.

```
   value<-c( 0.110546010137993, 9.95953827321208, 7.1751380374394, 285.658095052437,
   285.967649817749) 

   names(value)<-c( "C1", "Rc", "Rei", "Rf", "Rint")

ATi<-gsub("C1",value[["C1"]],ATi)
ATi<-gsub("Rf",value[["Rf"]],ATi)
ATi<-gsub("Rc",value[["Rc"]],ATi)
ATi<-gsub("Rint",value[["Rint"]],ATi)
ATi<-gsub("Rei",value[["Rei"]],ATi)
```

The result looks good but now I have a list of characters and i need an expression for the evaluation. So I use parse.

```
ATi<-parse(text=ATi)
ATi<-eval(ATi)
```

The result of this is 0 that is not correct. I expected a list of 8 number with just three 0.
I suppose that the error is on parse because the result of apply parse is:

```
structure(expression(-(1/(0.110546010137993 * 285.658095052437) + 
(1/(0.110546010137993 * 9.95953827321208) + (1/(0.110546010137993 * 285.967649817749)
+ 1/(0.110546010137993 * 7.1751380374394)))), 
1/(0.110546010137993 * 7.1751380374394), 0, 1/(0.110546010137993 * 285.967649817749), 
1/(0.110546010137993 * 285.658095052437), 1/(0.110546010137993 * 9.95953827321208), 
0, 0), 
srcfile = <environment>, wholeSrcref = structure(c(1L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 9L),
srcfile = <environment>, class = "srcref"))
```

and seems that I have just an expression, not 8, so i have one result.

I try also to evaluate each formula alone, in this case i have different error.
For the first formula I don't have problem using the code above.
For the second one Parse doesn't work because He doesn't like "/".

the second formula is:

```
a<-quote(1/(C1 * Rei))
a<-gsub("C1",value[["C1"]],a)
a<-gsub("Rei",value[["Rei"]],a)
```

After using gsub a looks wired

```
c("/", "1", "(0.110546010137993 * 7.1751380374394)")
```

and for that reason, probably, when I apply parse..

```
a<-parse(text=a)
Error in base::parse(...) : <text>:1:1: unexpected '/'
1: /
   ^
```

Any idea will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: You should provide dput(Ati) and dput(value).

Comment: I change my question. now there are the lists for reproduce the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsub` is for character strings, not for `language` objects. (and note that a `formula` is  class of object in `R` (not what you have here)

If you want to calculate the values (results) given a set of parameters use `eval`.

If you want to substitute in the values and return language objects, it will take some `do.call`, `substitute`, trickery

```
# a smaller example

l <- list(quote(-(1/(C1 * Rf) + (1/(C1 * Rc) + (1/(C1 * Ree) + 1/(C1 * Rei)))))
,quote(1/(C1 * Rei)), 0)

ATi <- list(C1  = 0.11054601,
            Ra  =   0.04522716,
            Rc  =   9.95953827,
            Ree =   1.65135221,
            Rei =   7.17513804,
            Rf  = 285.65809505)



# to find result use eval

sapply(l, eval, env= ATi)
# [1] -7.678626  1.260743  0.000000

# to substitute values for symbols

lapply(l, function(x) eval(do.call('substitute',list(enquote(x), env = ATi))))
str(res)
# List of 3
# $ : language -(1/(0.11054601 * 285.65809505) + (1/(0.11054601 *      9.95953827) + (1/(0.11054601 * 1.65135221) + 1/(0.11054601 *  ...
# $ : language 1/(0.11054601 * 7.17513804)
# $ : num 0
```

Comment: I thought `Ati` was the list of expressions and `value` was the named vector.

Comment: @Dwin -- You are correct (but i'm not changin' it (unless the OP provides a reproducible example)

Comment: Above there are my list. the problem is a little different. My list of parameters (value) is a list of numbers with names like attributes. In that case env doesn't work. I can't change manually the list because is very long and number and type of the parameters change each time. I'd like to have some more confortable

Comment: Use as.list. @MarcoGiuliani

Answer (score 1):

What about this? I think just changing your `value` variable from a **numeric** to a **list** will do the trick with mnel's sapply solution.

```
ATi<-list(quote(-(1/(C1 * Rf) + (1/(C1 * Rc) + (1/(C1 * Rint) + 1/(C1 * Rei))))),

          quote(1/(C1 * Rei)), 0, quote(1/(C1 * Rint)), quote(1/(C1 * Rf)),
          quote(1/(C1 * Rc)), 0, 0)
value<-c( 0.110546010137993, 9.95953827321208, 7.1751380374394, 285.658095052437,
          285.967649817749) 
names(value)<-c( "C1", "Rc", "Rei", "Rf", "Rint")
valuelist <- as.list(value)
sapply(ATi,eval,env=valuelist)
[1] -2.23231928  1.26074329  0.00000000  0.03163297  0.03166725  0.90827576  0.00000000  0.00000000
```